# ServiceStack Razor: how do I render a Html.Partial view inside a @section?

Tags: razor, servicestack

I am currently unable to get `@Html.Partial()` to render a view within a `@section`.

Is this supported in ServiceStack? In my example code below, the first partial (outside of the `@section`) **does** get rendered. Inside the `@section` only the surrounding HTML gets rendered.

My folder structure looks like this:

- /Views/

  - MyLayout.cshtml
  - MyView.cshtml
- /Shared/

  - _MyPartialView.cshtml

MyLayout.cshtml looks like this:

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<MyViewModelBase>
...

@RenderBody()

<div id="sidebar">
    @RenderSection("sidebar")
</div>
```

MyView.cshtml contains this:

```
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage<MyViewModel>

@{
    Layout = "MyLayout";
}

@Html.Partial("_MyPartialView")

@section sidebar {
    <h2>Side Bar</h2>

    @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView")

    <p>Some other content</p>
}
```

The partial view contains nothing but plain HTML.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either - might be a limitation of Razor?

Comment: @jeffgabhart I tested it on an ASP.net MVC4 app and works fine, so I think it is a bug in ServiceStack. Stepping through the ServiceStack source I can see the same code getting executed for both partials, but the one inside the section just doesn't appear, as if the partial content got written to a different output stream for some reason. 

I'd raise a bug report but they don't seem to allow it on their github project, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported the bug on Github a couple of days ago and @mythz commited a fix for the issue.

See my SO post: [Service Stack 4.0.15: Razor Partial not outputted inside @section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706219/service-stack-4-0-15-razor-partial-not-outputted-inside-section)

The good news is the fix is available 4.0.16 (pre-release) via Myget (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)

Here is the issue on Github:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/60

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this?

```
@{ var myPartialView = Html.Partial("_MyPartialView"); }

@section sidebar {
    <h2>Side Bar</h2>

    @myPartialView

    <p>Some other content</p>
}
```

since Html.Partial just returns a MvcHtmlString you can put it into a variable.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work - stepping through the ServiceStack code Html.Partial does try to create a MvcHtmlString from the result of RenderPartial() from the view engine, but it is always null.