# Service Stack 4.0.15: Razor Partial not outputted inside @section

Tags: servicestack, partials, sections, servicestack-razor

**Summary:**
Razor Partials don't get rendered inside a @section in ServiceStack 4.
This seems to be a bug in ServiceStack.Razor.

Version: ServiceStack 4.0.15

Affected Package: ServiceStack.Razor

Razor partials inside a section does not get rendered.

### Example

Inside _Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("JavascriptConfig", required: false)
```

Inside home.cshtml

```
@section JavascriptConfig {
    @Html.Partial("_routes", Model.Lang)
}
```

Inside _routes.cshtml

```
@model string
test
```

If I look at the source code of the rendered View, there is **no HTML** outputted.

Answer (score 1):

I reported the issue on Github and a fix was posted in less than 19 hours!
So, this issue is no longer an issue as of ServiceStack 4.0.16 (pre-release)

https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/60